# Freehand Drawing on Entire Screen

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi

I'm trying to make a simple little tool that would allow a user to switch from normal operation to a mode where all application messages are disabled and they can use the mouse to do some freehand drawing, then switch modes again to keep their drawing on the screen while they do whatever other normal stuff they want. This could, if I decide, evolve into a nice thing you could use to use a decorated screen by saving the decorations you do and loading them later.

When I started this (which was over half a year ago, soon after discovering the Windows API) I just did global mouse tracking and painted a circle wherever it was to a GetDC(NULL) hdc. The problems, of course, were that it would disappear when anything under it updated and would still have the mouse messages put through, so if I held down the button on the desktop, for example, it would put resizing rectangle things throughout the paintings.

Today, after finally having some spare time since the last major work on this most of that 6 months ago, I decided to remake it and see if I could achieve what I wanted. I made a transparent, topmost, WS_CHILD, layered, maximized window (basically the screen doesn't change, but there's a window on top of everything letting messages through). Next, I made it so that when it was in painting mode, it would set the alpha value to 1 and let the user paint. The thing I didn't realize until I did it was that since the alpha value of the window was 1, none of the painting would be visible.

Next, I tried using GetDC(NULL), but remembered that gets erased when something updates.

Now I just thought of using bitmaps and dcs to repeatedly store the screen into a dc, paint on another dc, and then copy it back to the one with the stored screen with transparency for the parts that aren't drawn on, and copy that back to the screen, but I'm losing a bit of heart. Here's my source code for that (the mask function is taken from [this tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/transparency.html)). Please tell me if some of this is unnecessary. I've used bitmaps for double buffering sure, but I'm not all that sure on where I need them.

```
//Global mask since it takes longer to make
HBITMAP mask;

//Window Procedure Start
HDC screenDC; //hdc for entire screen
screenDC = GetDC (NULL); //get DC for screen

HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC (screenDC); //create DC for holding the screen+paint
HBITMAP bm = CreateCompatibleBitmap (screenDC, GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN)); //create bitmap for memDC

HDC paintDC = CreateCompatibleDC (screenDC); //create DC to paint on
HBITMAP paintBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap (screenDC, GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN)); //create bitmap for paintDC

SelectObject (memDC, bm); //select bitmap into memDC
SelectObject (paintDC, paintBM); //select painting bitmap into paintDC
BitBlt (memDC, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN), screenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //copy screen to memDC
SetBkColor (paintDC, RGB(0,0,0)); //set background of paintDC to black so it's all transparent to start

//WM_CREATE
mask = CreateBitmapMask (bm, RGB(0,0,0)); //create black mask (paint colours are limited 1-255 now)

//painting is done into paintDC

//at end of Window Procedure
SelectObject (paintDC, mask); //select mask into paintDC
BitBlt (memDC, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN), paintDC, 0, 0, SRCAND); //this in combination with the next should make it bitblt with all of the black taken out I thought
SelectObject (paintDC, paintBM); //select bitmaps into DCs
SelectObject (memDC, bm);
BitBlt (memDC, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN), paintDC, 0, 0, SRCPAINT); //second part of transparent bitblt
BitBlt (screenDC, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics (SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics (SM_CYSCREEN), paintDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //copy memDC back to screen

DeleteObject (paintBM); //delete stuff
DeleteObject (mask);
DeleteDC (memDC);
DeleteDC (paintDC);
ReleaseDC (hwnd, screenDC);

//CreateBitmapMask() (taken directly from http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/transparency.html
HBITMAP CreateBitmapMask(HBITMAP hbmColour, COLORREF crTransparent)
{
HDC hdcMem, hdcMem2;
HBITMAP hbmMask;
BITMAP bm;

// Create monochrome (1 bit) mask bitmap.

GetObject(hbmColour, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);
hbmMask = CreateBitmap(bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, 1, 1, NULL);

// Get some HDCs that are compatible with the display driver

hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
hdcMem2 = CreateCompatibleDC(0);

SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmColour);
SelectObject(hdcMem2, hbmMask);

// Set the background colour of the colour image to the colour
// you want to be transparent.
SetBkColor(hdcMem, crTransparent);

// Copy the bits from the colour image to the B+W mask... everything
// with the background colour ends up white while everythig else ends up
// black...Just what we wanted.

BitBlt(hdcMem2, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

// Take our new mask and use it to turn the transparent colour in our
// original colour image to black so the transparency effect will
// work right.
BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem2, 0, 0, SRCINVERT);

// Clean up.

DeleteDC(hdcMem);
DeleteDC(hdcMem2);

return hbmMask;
}
```

I know that code may very well be horrible. I'm taking all suggestions into account, it's just that I'm not too clear with this subject, and don't get everything that's happening, which makes it hard to fix. This code runs for me by pretty much putting a fullscreen black rectangle every so often.

My main question is: Is there any way I can paint onto the screen without it getting erased when windows underneath update? The only real thing I can think of now would be to store *all* of the locations of the tiny line segments the user draws and keep redrawing them on top of the screen. At first glance it seems very inefficient and wasteful of memory.

Also, I was pretty sure while writing this that I didn't need any code examples for the theoretical stuff before the supplied code segments. Most of it is gone now, but this really is more of a theory issue.

EDIT:
I just found out about the TransparentBlt function which seemed perfect for the situation, so I tried using that instead of the SRCPAINT and SRCAND BitBlts and it produced the same result: a black rectangle covering the screen, sometimes having parts disappear when my mouse moves over things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way, perhaps:

When in non-drawing mode, use [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540(v=vs.85).aspx) to set a 'transparency key' color for the transparent window. Make the window's alpha fully opaque, but fill the window (FillRect or similar) with that key color, and it will all appear transparent. Then anything you draw in the non-key color will appear as solid, on top of all the windows beneath the transparent layered window.

To go into drawing mode, one approach is to create a new window with a captured bitmap of the desktop immediately under your transparent layer. Or avoid the bitmap, and make it slightly non-transparent and all a solid color - eg so it looks like the desktop is "greyed out". The key thing is that this window is not completely transparent, so it will be able to receive mouse input that you can then use to draw on the actual transparent layer.

Comment: Upon first glance, this idea seems simple and brilliant! I never thought of using 2 layered windows to achieve the effect I wanted, and graying out the desktop is made easy. The only reason I used LWA_ALPHA was so I could capture the mouse messages, as LWA_COLORKEY wouldn't, but another window underneath solves everything. I'll probably be a bit too busy with schoolwork to try this for a few days, but I'll let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be best of by creating a snapshot of the screen and save that in a bitmap (in the form of a memory DC) BEFORE you show a window which displays the contents of the memory DC in fullscreen. That way you actually fetch the messages caused by clicks etc on your own window and process them as usual.

1. Capture screen contents
2. Create window (full screen) and use captured contents
3. Do some drawing
4. Save the content (as bmp or anything fancy)
5. Close the window and return to regular desktop

Good idea?

Comment: The one problem I see with that (unless I'm thinking wrong) is that I can't keep what they paint after they switch back to where they can do everything else (i.e. this has the same effect as a layered window with a transparency of 1, except things underneath it update in real-time while I paint. Correct me if that's not what you meant. When I look back at the bitmaps, the one I'd want to save/load is paintBM - the one with the user's drawings. This can then put placed "on top" of one with the screen image, which can then be applied back to the screen.

Comment: Saving the drawing as a layer on top of the captured screen is no problem. But if I understand correctly you want the screen to be updated while you are drawing on it?

Comment: Kind of, the main thing is to be able to have the painting stick around after the mode is switched (and in case anyone's wondering, this is done via a hotkey processed by my window). The ultimate solution I can think of that seems impossible though is to have a window on top with the background transparent, but not anything put on after that. This would cause the window to stay there with the visible paint stuck on it, while any unpainted part would be invisible. If that's possible, I'd be very happy, but I didn't find anything like that :/

Comment: Actually, do you think it'd work if I use a global mouse hook, check to see whether paint mode is on, and if it is, draw to a layered window with transparent colour (0,0,0) with a background colour of (0,0,0) using LWA_COLORKEY, and draw from there (or send the appropriate messages to my window since it can't detect them)?

Comment: In that case you have two routes: 1. Create a conventional window which captures the screen beneath it and updates every, say 100 ms. Or 2. you create a layered window, but instead of setting the alpha to 1 for the whole window, you're using the alpha channel for each pixel. I think option 2 would be more appropriate in this case. But you'll have to figure how to use per pixel alpha channel transparency on a layered window. All the drawing can then be stored in a memory DC (with per pixel alpha channel) and on each WM_PAINT you just `AlphaBlend` it to the main window.

Comment: Hooking is unnecessary, and remember color values should be pre-multiplied by the alpha value when using the `AlphaBlend` function.

Comment: I'll try that, just have to learn how to use it. I'm looking at examples right now, and there's a good chance I won't incorporate it until I'm at school tomorrow :p

Comment: The AlphaBlend seems to be doing something, just a bit unpredictably, as I'm still playing around with it. I did manage to get a nice gradient on the desktop so it got darker as it went right though :p